# TypeError: MetaData.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'schema'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to execute sql query to get a pandas dataframe on postgres server using sqlalchemy

I made this class to connect to postgres server :

```
class Connection:

    def __init__(self):
        load_dotenv()
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(os.getenv('CONNECTION_STRING'))

        try:
            self.connection = engine.connect()
            print("Connected to server : SUCCESS")
        except SQLAlchemyError as error:
            raise f'[CONNECTION ERROR] {error}'

    def sql_to_frame(self, filename):

        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            query = file.read()

        dataframe = pd.read_sql(text(query), self.connection)

        return dataframe

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

on trying to use this `Connection` object :

```
data_server = Connection()
my_dataframe = data_server.sql_to_frame('data_table.sql')
```

I am receiving this following error :

[image: error_screenshot]

I am using `venv` with following packages :

```
Package              Version
-------------------- -----------
anyio                3.6.2
argon2-cffi          21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings 21.2.0
attrs                22.2.0
backcall             0.2.0
beautifulsoup4       4.11.2
bleach               6.0.0
cffi                 1.15.1
colorama             0.4.6
debugpy              1.6.6
decorator            5.1.1
defusedxml           0.7.1
entrypoints          0.4
fastjsonschema       2.16.2
ftfy                 6.1.1
fuzzywuzzy           0.18.0
greenlet             2.0.2
idna                 3.4
importlib-metadata   6.0.0
importlib-resources  5.10.2
ipykernel            6.16.2
ipython              7.34.0
ipython-genutils     0.2.0
ipywidgets           8.0.4
jedi                 0.18.2
Jinja2               3.1.2
joblib               1.2.0
jsonschema           4.17.3
jupyter              1.0.0
jupyter_client       7.4.9
jupyter-console      6.4.4
jupyter_core         4.12.0
jupyter-server       1.23.5
jupyterlab-pygments  0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets   3.0.5
Levenshtein          0.20.9
MarkupSafe           2.1.2
matplotlib-inline    0.1.6
mistune              2.0.4
nbclassic            0.5.1
nbclient             0.7.2
nbconvert            7.2.9
nbformat             5.7.3
nest-asyncio         1.5.6
notebook             6.5.2
notebook_shim        0.2.2
numpy                1.21.6
packaging            23.0
pandas               1.1.5
pandocfilters        1.5.0
parso                0.8.3
pickleshare          0.7.5
pip                  23.0
pkgutil_resolve_name 1.3.10
prometheus-client    0.16.0
prompt-toolkit       3.0.36
psutil               5.9.4
psycopg2             2.9.5
pycparser            2.21
Pygments             2.14.0
pyrsistent           0.19.3
python-dateutil      2.8.2
python-dotenv        0.21.1
python-Levenshtein   0.20.9
pytz                 2022.7.1
pywin32              305
pywinpty             2.0.10
pyzmq                25.0.0
qtconsole            5.4.0
QtPy                 2.3.0
rapidfuzz            2.13.7
scikit-learn         1.0.2
scipy                1.7.3
Send2Trash           1.8.0
setuptools           67.1.0
six                  1.16.0
sniffio              1.3.0
soupsieve            2.3.2.post1
SQLAlchemy           2.0.1
terminado            0.17.1
threadpoolctl        3.1.0
tinycss2             1.2.1
tornado              6.2
traitlets            5.9.0
typing_extensions    4.4.0
wcwidth              0.2.6
webencodings         0.5.1
websocket-client     1.5.0
wheel                0.38.4
widgetsnbextension   4.0.5
zipp                 3.12.0
```

- I have looked for similar issues but got no result from it
- My python version used to create `venv` in `python3.7`
- Is there any postgres driver that i have to import the sqlalchemy is using internally ?